# Google plugin for Eclipse

Tags: chrome, google-apps, eclipse

I am looking for an Eclipse plugin that would allow me to launch a Google search in Google Chrome based on the currently selected text in Eclipse, through a shortcut (or otherwise, less preferably, through an option in context menu, main menu or icon).

---

E.g.:

[image: Code marked in Eclipse]

→

[image: Google search for the marked code]